How to design a controller with bounded controller output?
I want to apply my theoretical knowledge about control theory in the real world.
Consider the following closed loop scenario:

In theory, my $U$ is not limited. In practice, the $U$ is bounded by some physical actor. For example a motor, which can only run at a certain speed. How do I take this into account when designing the controller?

A lot of systems have limited controller output and end up dong very little to change from the theory.
For example a room thermostat only has cool, off, and heat as outputs. That gets resolved by ending up with a pwm signal. However in that case you might need to account for cycle times and prevent short cycling by adding some hysteresis.
If U cannot be set to a value that would allow the error to become 0 eventually then the controlled system is undersized and you tell that to the stake holders.
If the lowest non-zero value you can set U to is big enough to get the error to zero then you need to see whether short cycling might be an issue. If the minimal cycle time would result in a too large swing then the system is oversized (again needs to be reported to stake holders).

This is a good example of a bounded actor. However, how do one deal with a motor controlling a vehicle moving forward and backward? In order to stop at a desired position, my K could just do a full speed approach to the position and then has to move the motor (faster than possible) in negative direction to avoid overshoots. I assume that I have to design K such that I avoid getting into U's non-linear domain.

Yeah you'll have to account for the speed (the D component in a PID) to slow down as you approach
